# Nested information in Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I access information that is in a "deeper" level of the snapshot? Do I always need to start another Query? To show you what I mean, I have a screenshot of my structure:
[Screenshot of DataStructure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIiRo.jpg)

I am loading all the posts in my query, I can read the author information etc, but how can I get the information inside options? I tried the following:

```
ref.child("posts").child("details").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in

        if snapshot.value == nil {
            return
        }
        let post = Post()
        guard let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary else {
            return
        }
        post.postID = snapshot.key
        post.title = snapshotValue["title"] as? String
        post.postDescription = snapshotValue["description"] as? String
        if (post.postDescription == ""){
            post.postDescription = "No description has been entered for this post.."
        }
        post.timestamp = snapshotValue["timestamp"] as? NSNumber

        let options = snapshotValue["options"]
        print(options)
```

when I print options, I can see the information, but when I try to cast it to NSDictionary or something to access it, it prints nil? I can also define a new attribute like post.options if that may help? Options is not always just 0 and 1, its variable, so I need to iterate through those. How can I achieve that?

Comment: If I understood correctly, `print(options)` actually prints your data, right? Its seems from the image that options is an array though so if you are casting it to a dictionary, it won't work. Maybe iterate through options with a for...each loop and print the content to see if you get your data

Comment: ok I will try that

Comment: I need to cast it somehow, otherwise options is of type Any?.. so I can't use a each loop for type any

Comment: Right, you'll need to cast it to an array instead of a dictionary.
Something like this would work:
`if let options = snapshotValue["options"] as? [Any] { 
    for option in options {
        print(option)
    }
} `

Comment: Sorry for the bad format, I can't seem to format multiple lines of code in the comments section.

Comment: no problem, I really appreciate your help! That seems to work, when I print each in options I get something like: {
    uri = "theURLStandsHereIJustDontShowYouxD";
    votes = 0;
} can I cast it again to a [Any] ? or how can I access the specific info now?

Comment: Please post Firebase structures as text, no images or links. Links expire and images are not searchable and often times an answer will contain a proposed structure and we don't want to have to retype all of that!

Comment: ok I found out that I can cast each in options to a NSDictionary and then get the info out of that Dictionary :) I really appreciate your help, if you want to answer with a real answer and not a comment, I will mark it as right

Comment: No problem at all. I was just in the process of doing so to be able to show you a correctly formatted answer :)

Comment: @cloo_coder At this point you should be moving away from NSDictionary and make it Swiftier. Also, the array you are using within Options is going to get you into trouble as arrays cannot be accessed by index - the entire array has to be loaded in order for you to acesss the individual elements, and the elements cannot be modified or removed - the entire array has to be deleted or re-written. You're also going to have issue with how the variables are cast as well.

Comment: @Jay so do you have some sample code on how you would solve that problem?

Comment: See my answer! Avoid Firebase array's as they are evil. When creating nodes, disassociate node names from the data they contain (generally) and create new nodes with childByAutoId. In this case, each child of options would have a discreet node name instead of 0,1, 2 etc. Each of those nodes could read, changed, deleted or queried without reading in the entire options node. Imagine if there were 10k votes/url's in options; to add one more, the entire node would have to be read, then updated in code and written. With nodes created with childByAutoId. add one and your done.. it's query able too!

Comment: Thanks for that answer, I will try it out as soon as possible! I got what you mean with the childByAutoID but in my case it's actually needed to call them 0,1,2,3,.. and even though I said that the number of options can be different, the max would be around 10 options in my case, so thanks for everything and the nice explanation, but in my case I guess I can use the numbers! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up the comments on the original question, you can access the option values like this:

```
if let options = snapshotValue["options"] as? [Any] { 
    for option in options {
        if let optionDict = option as? [String:Any] {
            let votes = optionDict["votes"] as? Int
            let url = optionDict["uri"] as? String
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @cloo_coder No no no. This is not a good answer. While it will work *sometimes*, what if options is a String or a Bool? You are assuming options is a Dictionary which  it *isn't* -  it's a Firebase array which in general should be avoided [Arrays are Evil](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html)

Comment: @Jay You are right that mainArray is incorrect and random and I changed it back to `options` as it should be. What I dont understand is if the OP knows that `options` is a Firebase child that he knows is a list of items, why can't he treat it as an `[Any]`?

Comment: snapshotValue does not have a value of ["options"] when it's defined as Any. Run the code yourself and you'll see that options is always nil with the OP's structure.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a greatly simplified answer that will work with the Firebase Structure presented (note that Firebase Array's should only be used in specific cases and generally should be avoided).

Given a structure

```
posts
  post_id_0
    caption: "some caption"
    comment: "some comment"
    options:
       0:
          votes: "10"
          url: "some url"
       1:
          votes: "20"
          url: "some url"
```

note that the structure is similar to the OP in that the options child node is a Firebase array where each index also contains child nodes. So the key is the index (0, 1, 2) and the child of each is a dictionary of key:values pairs (votes: value and url: value)

The following code will read in this specific node, print the caption and comments and then iterate over the options ARRAY and print the votes and URL for each child in the array

```
ref.child("posts").child("post_id_0")
                  .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
     //treat the whole node as a dictionary
     let postDict = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]

     //and since it's a dictionary, access each child node as such       
     let caption = postDict["caption"] as! String
     let comment = postDict["comment"] as! String

     print("caption: \(caption)  comment: \(comment)")

     //the options child node is an array of indexes, each with
     //   a dictionary of child nodes     
     let options = postDict["options"] as! [[String:Any]] //array of dictionaries

     //now iterate over the array      
     for option in options {
          let votes = option["votes"] //each option child is a dict
          let url = option["url"]
          print("votes \(votes!)  url: \(url!)")
     }
})
```

Note that we indicate the structure of the options child node like this

```
let options = postDict["options"] as! [[String:Any]]
```

which is an array of key:value (String:Any) dictionaries

A very important point that the the entire options node must be read in to work with it. If there are 10k children, it becomes highly inefficient. It's also not queryable so if you want to count how many duplicate url's there are, the entire node must be read in and then parsed.

A better option is to use childByAutoId to create node key names

```
posts
  post_id_0
    caption: "some caption"
    comment: "some comment"
    options:
       -Yuijjismisdw
          votes: "10"
          url: "some url"
       -YJ989jijdmfm
          votes: "20"
          url: "some url"
```

Yuijjismisdw was created with childByAutoId.